# Inputmask con valores determinados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando input mask para un formato de teléfono:

```
$('.selector').inputmask("(09\\1) 999-9999");
```

el 0 y el 1 son estándar, y solamente almaceno los demás números, el problema es que al volver a cargar mi página si los complete con '1111111' pierdo el último número porque lo toma como parte de la mascara

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

yo obtengo primero los numeros con una expresion regular

```
var telefonoCasa = $("#telefonoCasa").val().match( /\d+/g);
telefonoCasa = telefonoCasa.join("");
```

ya tendrias todos los numeros del input y haz tus validaciones si no quieres almacenar el 1 y el 0